# Error in defining the input for a class in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried giving the input as input channel and output channel as tf.constant tensor. But the code shows error as input for the class must be a vector of `{int32,int64}`, got shape `[2,1]`. I defined the GTLayer class as follows :

**Importing libraries:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
```

**GTLayer class:**

```
class GTLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, first=True):
        super(GTLayer, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.first = first
        if self.first == True:
            self.conv1 = GTConv(in_channels, out_channels)
            self.conv2 = GTConv(in_channels, out_channels)
        else:
            self.conv1 = GTConv(in_channels, out_channels)
    
    def forward(self, A, H_=None):
        if self.first == True:
            a = self.conv1(A)
            b = self.conv2(A)
            #H = torch.bmm(a,b)
            H = tf.matmul(a, b)

            #W = [(F.softmax(self.conv1.weight, dim=1)).detach(),(F.softmax(self.conv2.weight, dim=1)).detach()]
            W = [tf.stop_gradient(tf.nn.softmax(self.conv1.weight, axis=1).numpy()),
                 tf.stop_gradient(tf.nn.softmax(self.conv1.weight, axis=1).numpy()) ]

        else:
            a = self.conv1(A)
            #H = torch.bmm(H_,a)
            H = tf.matmul(H_, a)
            #W = [(F.softmax(self.conv1.weight, dim=1)).detach()]
            W = [tf.stop_gradient(tf.nn.softmax(self.conv1.weight, axis=1).numpy())]
        return H,W
```

**GTConv layer**

```
class GTConv(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(GTConv, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.weight = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(in_channels, out_channels)),
            trainable=True)
        self.bias = None
        self.scale = tf.Variable([0.1] , trainable=False)
        self.reset_parameters()

        #self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_channels,in_channels,1,1))
        #self.bias = None
        #self.scale = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([0.1]), requires_grad=False)
        
    def reset_parameters(self):
        n = self.in_channels
        tf.fill(self.weight, 9)
        #if self.bias is not None:
        #    fan_in, _ = nn.init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
        #   bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
        #    nn.init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)
    
    def forward(self, A):
        A = tf.add_n(tf.nn.softmax(self.weight))
        return A
```

**input:**

```
inp = tf.constant([4])
out = tf.constant([2])
```

**Error:**

**output:**

```
d = GTLayer(inp, out)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 d = GTLayer(inp, out)
>
> 5 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    7184 def
> raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):    7185   e.message += (" name: " +
> name if name is not None else "")
> -> 7186   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access    7187     7188
>
> InvalidArgumentError: shape must be a vector of {int32,int64}, got
> shape [2,1] [Op:RandomStandardNormal]

Comment: Why are you passing hyperparameters as tf.constant's? Obviously it does not work that way.

Comment: For debugging the code, actually I'm trying to remodel a Pytorch code into tensorflow framework! The original Pytorch code for above can be found at source: [link](https://github.com/seongjunyun/Graph_Transformer_Networks/blob/master/model.py). It is the 2nd class (named GTLayer) in this model_py module.

Comment: This does not really answer what I asked.

Comment: Okay, So basically you wish to know why a constant value is fed into the class? I mean we will anyway need to give the value of these hyperparameters, i.e (in_channels, out_channels). Doesn't hyperparameters mean that we need to iterate and check what works well for our model in terms of efficiency and accuracy? Is there any other way in which I should've defined them? I am very new to tensorflow framework that's why I am not able to understand your question well!

Comment: The thing is that you do not need to pass tf.constants for these parameters, just pass integers.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried passing integer values as, `inp = 4`, `out = 2` and `d = GTLayer(inp, out)` . The following **error** shows up : InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'index_type' of float is not in the list of allowed values: int32, int64
 ; NodeDef: {{node Fill}}; Op<name=Fill; signature=dims:index_type, value:T -> output:T; attr=T:type; attr=index_type:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]> [Op:Fill]

Comment: That is a different problem that should be debugged separately.